# Should Magento base url include www?

Tags: magento

In the Magento installation wizard, should the base url include `www` or not?

Ex: `www.site.com` or `site.com`

Comment: It depends on what you want. I would Google `www or not` for some helpful articles

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using a cdn to distribute your images, etc. yes, it would be a really, really good idea to have your web server use a www. host name instead of using only the bare domain name.

It's not cool when your customers start having blecherous cookie problems due to not using proper host names to sort out the different cname entries in your DNS.

Changing after the fact results in humorous non-SEO friendly reindexing by Google, Bing, et. al.